# Installed Windows service will not start

Tags: c#, service

Ok, I hate being stumped but I am this time.  I was able to get the service to install just fine so that works good.  When I start the service, it stops and I am getting no details on what is wrong.  So here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyServiceImport
{

public partial class MyServiceData : ServiceBase
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private Double ReadTime = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReadTime")) * 1000 * 60;
    private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
    Thread _thread;

    public MyServiceData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // These lines run when the service starts up
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Interval = ReadTime;
        _timer.Start();

        #region Write to Audit Log
        string Event = "Update Service";
        string DoneBy = "Automation User";
        string Information = "Update Service has Started.";
        string MyTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBUtils.MyService_DBString);
        string writeit = "INSERT INTO MyService_Activities (Event, DoneBy, Information, TimeStamp) values(@Event, @DoneBy, @Information, @TimeStamp)";
        SqlCommand WriteLog = new SqlCommand(writeit, conn);
        conn.Open();
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Event", Event);
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("DoneBy", DoneBy);
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Information", Information);
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeStamp", MyTimeStamp);
        WriteLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        #endregion

    }

    // writes message into the activity log that the service has stopped.
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        #region Write to Audit Log
        string Event = "Update Service";
        string DoneBy = "Automation User";
        string Information = "Update Service has Stopped.";
        string MyTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBUtils.MyService_DBString);
        string writeit = "INSERT INTO MyService_Activities (Event, DoneBy, Information, TimeStamp) values(@Event, @DoneBy, @Information, @TimeStamp)";
        SqlCommand WriteLog = new SqlCommand(writeit, conn);
        conn.Open();
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Event", Event);
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("DoneBy", DoneBy);
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Information", Information);
        WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeStamp", MyTimeStamp);
        WriteLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        #endregion
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // set up connection string 
        string _csMyServiceDD = DBUtils.MyService_DBString;
        string DoImportNow = string.Empty, TaskDay = string.Empty, TaskStartTime = string.Empty, TaskEndTime = string.Empty;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_csMyServiceDD);
        // Get task variables from database for comparison
        string query = "SELECT TaskDay, TaskStartTime, TaskEndTime FROM MyService_TaskSchedule where TaskName = 'DoImport'";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        // opens the connection to read
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr1.Read())
        {
            TaskDay = rdr1.GetValue(0).ToString();
            TaskStartTime = rdr1.GetValue(1).ToString();
            TaskEndTime = rdr1.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }
        // closing the connection
        conn.Close();

        // setting _lastRun variable to this moment.
        _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
        // stop the timer 
        _timer.Stop();
        try
        {
            // check if the current time is within the time range for this service task.
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == TaskDay && DateTime.Now > Convert.ToDateTime(TaskStartTime) && DateTime.Now < Convert.ToDateTime(TaskEndTime))
            {
                _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ImportData));
                _thread.Name = "ImportData";
                _thread.Start();
            }
            // decide if there is something to do
            #region Write to Audit Log
            string Event = "Update Service";
            string DoneBy = "Automation User";
            string Information = "Update Service has started importing data.";
            string MyTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            string writeit = "INSERT INTO MyService_Activities (Event, DoneBy, Information, TimeStamp) values(@Event, @DoneBy, @Information, @TimeStamp)";
            SqlCommand WriteLog = new SqlCommand(writeit, conn);
            conn.Open();
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Event", Event);
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("DoneBy", DoneBy);
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Information", Information);
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeStamp", MyTimeStamp);
            WriteLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Catch error and write to audit log
            #region Write to Audit Log
            string Event = "Update Service";
            string DoneBy = "Automation User";
            string Information = "Error occurred in Import - Message: " + ex.ToString() + "";
            string MyTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            string writeit = "INSERT INTO MyService_Activities (Event, DoneBy, Information, TimeStamp) values(@Event, @DoneBy, @Information, @TimeStamp)";
            SqlCommand WriteLog = new SqlCommand(writeit, conn);
            conn.Open();
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Event", Event);
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("DoneBy", DoneBy);
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("Information", Information);
            WriteLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeStamp", MyTimeStamp);
            WriteLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            #endregion
        }
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You need to improve your question. It's not likely that anyone is going to do a codereview for you, so you'll need to provide us a lot more information (this requires a bunch of debug/audit trail information logged so that you/we can figure this out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the entire thing, first just doing a basic service start-up, then I added my code to it.  Working well now.  Thanks everyone for the tips and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your catch{} works as intended? I suspect you don't get any feedback because your  SQLConnection doesn't work properly. Try doing a simpler logging to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and tags don't give us much to go on.  You're using C#?  And, I'm assuming Visual Studio?

What has really helped me debug services is [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

You install it through NuGet and it's pretty easy to get going for a beginner.  [Here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial) is just one of many excellent tutorials.  I write to plain old .txt files.

You basically put a bunch of log comments in throughout your code and then try and start your service.  When it fails, you open up the log .txt and see what the last thing written was.  You now know it failed in between that log line and your next log line.

After you feel comfortable with NLog, you can even put a global, unhandled-error catcher in your code and write the `Exception` to NLog which will write the StackTrace to your log and give you much more detailed information.  Your NLog.config file must be set up to format `Exception`s into text.